Refactoring Slider Class - Using Vanilla JS
As a part of building a new website, i created a slider using Class in JS. Since I've not used Class much, I'd like to know how to refactor the code for better readability (i think it has got good readability) and efficient.
1 main thing I've introduced is loading image URL from data attributes rather than direct img urls to reduce load on initial page loading. This was the main reason why I started creating this Class. I'm also planning on introducing another functionality for loading  element rather than 
class Slider {
  #imgHeight;
  #imgWidth;
  #sliderScrollWidth;
  #currentScroll;
  #slides = [];
  #sliderInterval = null;
  #slider = null;
  #slide = null;
  #sliderScrollArea = null;

  constructor(config = {}) {
    this.config = config;

    this.#imgHeight = null;
    this.#imgWidth = null;
    this.#sliderScrollWidth = 0;
    this.#currentScroll = 0;
    this.currentSlide = 1;
    this.slideCount = 0;
    this.gapBetweenSlides = null;

    // Dom Selectors
    this.#slides = [];

    // status
    this.sliderIsStopped = false;
    this.sliderIsPaused = false;

    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.createSlider();
    this.initializeSlides();
    this.assignSlideDimensions();
    if (this.config.autoplay) this.autoPlay();
  }

  createSlider() {
    this.#slider = document.getElementById(this.config.id);
    if (!this.#slider) {
      console.error(`Slider with id ${this.config.id} not found. Check your code. `);
      return;
    }

    this.#slides = this.#slider.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    this.#sliderScrollArea = this.#slider.querySelector(".slider__scrollarea");

    this.#sliderScrollWidth = this.#sliderScrollArea.scrollWidth;

    if (this.config.pauseOnHover) {
      this.#slider.addEventListener("mouseover", () => this.stopSlider());
      this.#slider.addEventListener("mouseout", () => this.playSlider());
    }

    if (this.config.sliderNavButtonVisible) {
      this.#slider.querySelector(".slider-prev-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (this.currentSlide <= 1) return;
        this.goToPrevSlide();
      });
      this.#slider.querySelector(".slider-next-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (this.currentSlide >= this.slideCount) return;
        this.goToNextSlide();
      });
    }
  }

  initializeSlides() {
    Object.values(this.#slides).map((slide) => {
      const imgURL = slide.getAttribute("data-img-url");
      const altText = slide.getAttribute("data-img-alt");
      slide.innerHTML = `<img src="${imgURL}" alt="${altText}" />`;
    });
    this.#slide = this.#slider.querySelector(".slide");
    this.slideCount = this.#slides.length;
  }

  autoPlay() {
    if (this.sliderIsStopped) return;
    this.#sliderInterval = setInterval(
      () => {
        if (this.currentSlide >= this.slideCount) {
          this.resetSlidePosition();
        } else {
          this.goToNextSlide();
        }
      },
      this.config.delay ? this.config.delay : 0
    );
  }

  goToNextSlide() {
    this.#currentScroll += this.#imgWidth + this.gapBetweenSlides;
    this.#sliderScrollArea.scrollTo({ left: this.#currentScroll });
    this.currentSlide += 1;
  }

  goToPrevSlide() {
    this.#currentScroll -= this.#imgWidth + this.gapBetweenSlides;
    this.#sliderScrollArea.scrollTo({ left: this.#currentScroll });
    this.currentSlide -= 1;
  }

  resetSlidePosition() {
    this.#sliderScrollArea.scrollTo({ left: 0 });
    this.#currentScroll = 0;
    this.currentSlide = 1;
  }

  stopSlider() {
    this.sliderIsStopped = false;
    clearInterval(this.#sliderInterval);
  }

  assignSlideDimensions() {
    this.#imgWidth = this.#slide.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    this.#imgHeight = this.#slide.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const slidesWidth = this.#imgWidth * this.#slides.length;
    this.gapBetweenSlides = (this.#sliderScrollWidth - slidesWidth) / (this.#slides.length - 1);
  }
}


I recommend checking out Clean Code by Robert C. Martin. it offers great tips for writing clear and maintainable code. The Pragmatic Programmer and Code Complete are also worth a look if you're interested in improving your coding skills.
